# Drag a div smoothly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a draggable div. I wonder how I could improve the regarding browser rendering and a smooth result.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCWbC/20/)

reactJS

```
 mouseDown() {
this.setState({
  thumbActive: true,
});
},

mouseUp() {
this.setState({
  thumbActive: false,
});
},

mouseMove(e) {
  if(!this.state.thumbActive) {
  return;
  }

  const y = e.nativeEvent.offsetY;
  this.setState({
  topPosition: y,
  });
},
```

HTML

```
  <div
      className='scroll'
      onMouseMove={this.mouseMove}
    >
      <div className={this.state.thumbActive ? 'thumb pointer-events-none' : 'thumb'}
        onMouseDown={this.mouseDown}
        onMouseUp={this.mouseUp}
        style={{top: this.state.topPosition}}
      />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with drag and drop plugins, which saves lots of time.

plugin - [react-dnd](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd)